# Switching stacks efficiently

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, context-switch

Due to some reason, I switch the stack for calling some functions in my application. I use **makecontext/getcontext/swapcontext** for that purpose. However, I find it to be too slow.
I tried to use custom made code for that purpose, which saves the stack pointer and other registers and then assign the stack pointer the value of the new memory which I want to use as a stack. However, I keep getting **stack smashing detected** error.

Are there some special permissions set for the stack by the OS or else what is the matter here? How to circumvent the problem.

Comment: You'll need to post some actual code that exhibits the problem if you want to get any meaningful answers

Comment: @MetallicPriest: you are probably doing something which interests me (and I probably did similar stuff ten years ago, so I believe I could help you). But to get real help, you should explain your overall goal (I'm guessing it could be related to some persistency or checkpoint mechanism), and you'll get much more help if you put all your current software as free software on some public repository (like github...). I'm much more motivated to help on free software than on proprietary one....

Comment: @nos, I was also thinking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excellent [GNU Pth](http://www.gnu.org/s/pth/) library makes heavy use of these techniques. It's very well documented, and determines the most efficient context switching mechanism at compile time. **edit:** at configure time actually.

The author's paper: `rse-pmt.ps` gives a technical account of user-space context switching and related issues - alternative signal stacks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at other software doing the same dirty tricks as you do. In particular [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/). You might perhaps consider using `longjmp` after manually doing dirty things on the target `jmp_buf`. Of course, none of this is portable.

But please **explain more your overall goal**. Your questions are generally too mysterious....
(and that is repulsive to some)

Answer (score 1):

The *makecontext()*/*getcontext()*/*setcontext()*/*swapcontext()* are quite efficient as they merely save the current values of the processor registers. However, in Linux/GLIBC at least, *setcontext()* and *getcontext()* invoke the *rt_sigprocmask()* system call to save/restore the signal mask of the calling thread. This may be the reason why you face some performance issues as this triggers a context switch into the kernel.